# singularity of $\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I was wondering why $0$ is not a singularity of $\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}$

Thank you for your feedbacks

Comment: $z/\sinh (z)=2z/(e^z-e^{-z})$ tends to $\lim_{z\to 0}2/2e^z=1$ by L'Hopital.

Comment: Alright, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is a removable discontinuity, $$\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{2z}{e^{z}-e^{-z}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{2}{2e^{z}}=1\neq\infty
 $$

Comment: That answers my question, thank you for all :))

Answer (score 2):

With the theory of power expansions, this is easier to see from the inverted function $\frac{\sinh z}{z}$. We have
$$
\sinh z = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2} = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\frac{z^n - (-z)^n}{2} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\frac{z^n - (-z)^n}{2}
$$
since the constant term vanishes. We then get that
$$
\frac{\sinh z}{z} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\frac{z^{i-1} + (-z)^{i-1}}{2}
$$
where the right-hand side is defined and equal to $1$ for $z = 0$. Of course, the function itself is undefined for $z = 0$, but taking the limit of the above equation as $z \to 0$ shows that this is a removable singularity.

Answer (score 0):

Take the limit (using De L'Hospital), and you'll find out that it is evaluated to $1$.